# Jasper reports database connection test succeeds only once

Tags: jdbc, jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to develop a JasperReport, so I am setting the following JDBC connection:
[image]

The problem is that **Test** button only succeeds the first time I push it. After that, all other tests (or any other attempt to access the database) fail with the following error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.sql.SQLException: Fallo al obtener un bloqueo en la base de datos: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@3e013c76[file =/Applications/TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio 6.16.0.app/Contents/MacOS/165.227.109.78:5432.lck, exists=true, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: checkHeartbeat read: 2021-02-03 16:17:16 heartbeat - read: -849 ms.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:126)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.AbstractDataAdapterService.test(AbstractDataAdapterService.java:120)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.wizard.AbstractDataAdapterWizard$3.runOperations(AbstractDataAdapterWizard.java:155)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.utils.jobs.CheckedRunnableWithProgress$1.run(CheckedRunnableWithProgress.java:51)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fallo al obtener un bloqueo en la base de datos: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@3e013c76[file =/Applications/TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio 6.16.0.app/Contents/MacOS/165.227.109.78:5432.lck, exists=true, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: checkHeartbeat read: 2021-02-03 16:17:16 heartbeat - read: -849 ms.
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.getConnection(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:164)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:124)
    ... 4 more
```

Actually, any first attempt to access the database succeeds, but any other after it fails with the same exception.

I'll appreciate any help about it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by downloading jdbcDriver.jar then adding it to Driver Classpath.
You should try it.